# Haskell reading args value

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, args

I'm having a bit problem with reading argument value in haskell:

I'm having options declared like this:

```
options :: [OptDescr ArgFlag]
options = [Option [] ["help"] (NoArg Help) "",
           Option [] ["version"] (NoArg Version) "",
           Option ['a'] [] (NoArg FSAll) "",
           Option ['L'] [] (ReqArg FSLevel "NUM") ""]
```

And I read the arguments like this (I can read which argument is active):

```
main = do
         args <- getArgs
         case getOpt RequireOrder options args of
             ([Version], [], []) -> do ...

             ([Help], [], []) -> do ...

             (flags, files, []) -> do ........ *

             otherwise -> do ...
```

Where there is '*' character, I need to read value of possible '-l 3' flag -> I searched through google but I haven't found nothing (maybe wrong keyword though). They just detect whether argument is active everywhere, not its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have defined

```
data ArgFlag = Help
             | Version
             | FSAll
             | FSLevel String
```

With a helper function

```
unFSLevel :: ArgFlag -> Maybe String
unFSLevel (FSLevel value) = Just value
unFSLevel _               = Nothing
```

you can then get the value like this:

```
case listToMaybe $ mapMaybe unFSLevel of
     Just value -> -- code to handle the -L flag having this value
     Nothing    -> -- code to handle there not being an -L flag
```

(You will need to import `mapMaybe` and `listToMaybe` from [Data.Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.0.0/Data-Maybe.html).)